React: Anchor tag takes several seconds to work
I have a React application that uses Material UI to render a login button.  I am passing an href to <Button> as discussed here and elsewhere to render an <a>.  The href points to an external url (i.e. our login provider).
There is 1 specific page of the application that exhibits some faulty behavior.  The initial render of the page results in an anchor tag with the expected href.  But when I click the link, nothing happens.  I'll click repeatedly for ~5 seconds and eventually I am redirected to the external link.
I have logged the event and event.target is consistently an a.Button-root element.  I see no difference between events that do not open the external link and events that do.
What's even more baffling is that the issue only seems to appear after the page is loaded via a window.location.replace in our code.  If I hard refresh the page, the login button works immediately, every time.
FWIW the login button's href is generated programmatically.  I thought initially there was a long delay between the rendering of the button and the generation of its href but this is not the case.  The href is generated before I can even move my mouse to the button to click it.
Has anyone experienced anything like this?  Any ideas of what else to investigate?
